# Parsed long date returns invalid year params

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have a long number that will be converted to date,

```
635759785190887215
```

Now when i parsed this number, it gives me an invalid date

```
from logs:
  Wed Aug 02 18:48:07 PST 20148395
```

year `20148395` is invalid. What could have been wrong?
The number is fetched from a web api and according to the developer he created those long numbers through Microsoft.net 'ticks'. I am trying to convert it to java date. I also tried using online long to date converter and i still got the same results.

I am trying to get difference in minutes between now and the long date 635759785190887215

Here's my code:

```
 String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a",new Date(pastDateInLong)).toString();
    Log.v(TAG,"PAST DATE: "+dateString);

    Date lastUpdate = new Date(pastDateInLong);
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    Log.v(TAG,"Comparing: Now>"+currentDate.toString()+" to "+lastUpdate.toString()+ "= "+(currentDate.getTime()- lastUpdate.getTime()));
    if (currentDate.getTime() - lastUpdate.getTime() >= 25*60*1000) {
        Log.v(TAG,"more than 25 minutes difference");
    }
    else{
        Log.v(TAG,"not more than 25 minutes difference");
    }
```

Comment: You should read up about the relationship between ticks and milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: i hvae read that every tick is equivalent to 0.0001 milliseconds, am i following the right lead?

Comment: It isn't simply a multiplicative difference. [Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx): "The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001"; zero milliseconds in Java is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: how can i convert those ticks to a date on java?

Comment: Search for "convert .net ticks to java date" on your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the value i have is using the Epoch, all I have to do is subtract epoch value of January 1, 1970 to my long number then divide it by 10,000.

```
public Date getDateFromTick(long ticks){
    final long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
    final long TICKS_PER_MILLIS = 10000;

    Date date = new Date((ticks-TICKS_AT_EPOCH)/TICKS_PER_MILLIS);
    Log.v(TAG, "DATE:>> (" + ticks + ") to " + date.toString());

    return date;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have passed wrong parameter for `Date` class. `java.util.Date` takes milliseconds as parameter.

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get current [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (in milliseconds). Although if you create an object of `Date` class without passing any parameter it will return current date.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns milliseconds since January 1, 1970

Eg., `Date date = new Date(64060588799000L);`

The above statement returns a date of 31 Dec 3999 23:59:59 GMT, your example is ~9924 times larger than that.